# Presence of junk characters while crawling a Russian website

Tags: java, linux, encoding, web-crawler, cyrillic

I am trying to crawl a Russian website in Linux,  but the output seems to be junk characters. 
The website is encoded in UTF-8 and while reading I am setting the encoding as UTF-8. However this doesn't seem to solve the problem.
What should I do to read it ?

```
public class Crawl {   
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    URL my_url = new URL("http://www.fmsmoscow.ru/docs/migration_registration/registration.html");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream(),"UTF-8"));
    while (null != (strTemp = br.readLine())){
    System.out.println(strTemp);
        }
    }   
}
```

Above is the code for the same.
I am exporting the code as jar and adding it in the Linux server.
Then I am executing it to get the output in the Linux console.

Comment: There are nowhere near enough details in this question to be able to help in any way.

Comment: Tell me what details you require and i'll give them.

Comment: 1) "website is encoded in UTF-8" - how have you confirmed that? 2) "while reading I am setting the encoding as UTF-8" - what does that mean exactly? Code please. 3) "the output seems to be junk characters" - where how when what are you outputting to?

Comment: I know that the website is encoded in UTF-8 on viewing its page source. URL my_url = new URL("http://www.fmsmoscow.ru/docs/migration_registration/registration.html");BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream(),"Cp1251"));  while (null != (strTemp = br.readLine())){ System.out.println(strTemp);}

Comment: 1) Is this Java we're talking about? 2) Why are you setting the encoding to `Cp1251` explicitly even though the site is supposedly UTF-8 encoded? 3) Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29124804/edit) and add code to it (and the appropriate tags for whatever language you're using).

Comment: That page is *not* encoded in UTF-8, the HTTP headers specify `windows-1251`.

Comment: Yes, it is just a demo page, but the one I need to crawl is in UTF-8. I can't give that URL for client confidentiality reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In general you could also store the content binary (as-is), and then look where it goes wrong. Say in a programmer's editor like JEdit or NotePad++ that can switch encodings. It might be slipped in HTML comments with native Windows-1251. *Maybe stripping HTML comments helps.*

For fault tolerant decoding, error reporting, one needs a [CharsetDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html).

```
CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder(); // ISO_8859_1
decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream(), decoder);
```

:
See the javadoc on REPLACE, REPORT. If you want more, the approach is different. You need to read the input, place the bytes in a ByteBuffer, and then

```
CoderResult result = decoder(byteBuffer, charBuffer, true /*EOF*/);
```

---

To pick Cyrillic sequences out of UTF-8 one can check for the validity of UTF-8 sequences:

- 0xxxxxxx
- 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
- 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
- ...

Hence (untested):

```
void patchMixOfUtf8AndCp1251(byte[] bytes, StringBuilder sb) {
    boolean priorWrongUtf8 = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        byte b = bytes[i];
        if (b >= 0) {
            sb.appendCodePoint((int)b);
            priorWrongUtf8 = false;
        } else {
            int n = highBits(b); // Also # bytes in sequence
            boolean isUTF8 = !priorWrongUtf8
                    && 1 < n && n <= 6
                    && i + n <= bytes.length;
            if (isUTF8) {
                for (int j = 1; j < i + n; ++j) {
                     if (highBits(bytes[j]) != 1) {
                         isUTF8 = false;
                         break;
                     }
                }
            }
            if (isUTF8) {
                sb.append(new String(bytes, i, i + n, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                i += n - 1;
            } else {
                // UTF-8 Continuation char must be Cp1252.
                sb.append(new String(bytes, i, i + 1, "Windows-1251"));
            }
            priorWrongUtf8 = !isUTF8;
        }
    }
}

private int highBits(byte b) {
    int n = 0;
    while (n < 8 && ((1 << (7 - n)) & b) != 0) {
        ++n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

As it is unlikely that Cyrillic is immediately concatenated to UTF-8, a state `priorWrongUtf8` is used.

Comment: It goes wrong when it encounters a Russian character, It is crawling the rest of the page perfectly.

Comment: Added a patch function (untested!). Such things can work to a limited extend.